# Autofill not recognizing characters after slash

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm trying to use autofill in a radtextbox, which appeared to be working well but I'm having a strange issue.

Here is my code:

```
 var tb = ((TextBox)((RadTextBoxItem)txIndexNo1.RootElement
                      .Children[0].Children[0]).HostedControl);  
 var ls = Lnq.NOs.Select(a => (a.Index)).ToArray();
 tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(ls);
 tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
 tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

The strings should be: (Example)

```
123445/14
16277/14
```

However I only autofill until the Backslash ?

[image]

Is this because it is an escape character ??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an issue in the .NET TextBox, which RadTextBox hosts. Here is the issue replicated with only the .NET control:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Parent = this;
var ls = new string[] { "123445/14", "16277/14" };
tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(ls);
tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

I would suggest to use Telerik's [RadTextBoxControl](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/editors-textboxcontrol-autocomplete.html), which is their implementation of a text box. Here is an example:

```
RadTextBoxControl rtbc = new RadTextBoxControl();
rtbc.Parent = this;
rtbc.AutoCompleteDataSource = new string[] { "123445//14", "16277//14" };
rtbc.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
```